# plist xml file to html /pdf format on mac

Tags: html, xml, macos, xslt, ios-ui-automation

i am working on ios UI Automation. 
i get test results in plist which is a xml document but this is not a readable form. so i need to convert this format to some readable one in some automated way.

what is the best way to **convert xml into html or pdf** through some script (may be apple script) ?
here is my sample xml code
    
    
    
    
    All Samples
        
            
                LogType
                Error
                Message
                Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Can't find variable: localTarget
                Timestamp
                2011-12-20T09:22:44Z
                Type
                10
            
        
        version
        2

Let me know if i need to give more detail on requirement

Thanks!!

Comment: Such transformations can easily be performed with XSLT, provided you edit the question and define what is "readable" -- the exact wanted result. Also, format your XML document in the proper way to make it visible.

Comment: Readble means a HTML or PDF format which will be showing tables having information for test cases, result(pass or fail) and screen shots taken during test execution.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same and this is a really good blog on how to implement it.

http://blog.essencework.com/post/1728269540/xcode-uiautomation-for-test-result-report-part-2